# Dynamic Linking on classic ASP pages not working

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, upgrade

We are attempting an upgrade of our development environment from Tridion 5.3 to 2011 and we still have a couple of publications that are using classic ASP which for various reasons we haven't been able to upgrade yet.

Dynamic linking for pages using .NET webcontrols is working fine but we are getting the following error on any classic ASP pages with dynamic linking.

> Server object error 'ASP 0193 : 80020009'
>
> OnStartPage Failed
>
> /dlinka.asp, line 63
>
> An error occurred in the OnStartPage method of an external object.

The deprecated windows service executables have been copied from the installation media to the /Tridion_Root/bin folder.

The server is 32 bit Windows Server 2003 and running IIS 6.0

Comment: Is OnStartPage your own code? The error looks like something from ADODB. Are you able to debug into it to isolate the problem?

Comment: I stripped everything out so the only code in the page is the ASP dynamic component link code.

Comment: @RobEades the Server object error seems to refer to http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;191410 can you perhaps provide a bit more detail and a new example of what error you get on what line (with code)?

Comment: @Bart Koopman  We looked into the link you refer to but the suggested resolution was to enable session state which we knew was enabled.  As mentioned the only code was the dynamic component link:
`<%=Server.CreateObject("cd_link.ComponentLink").getLinkAsString("tcm:0-46-1", "tcm:46-214152-64", "tcm:46-214150", "tcm:0-0-0", "", "TEST PAGE B", True, False)%>`

In the end what resolved this was to reinstall IIS completely on the server.  This fixed the issue we were seeing.  Hopefully this will help anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling IIS 6.0 on the server resolved the issue.